# How to style SVG > Image code (no path) via CSS?

Tags: html, css, svg

We exported a .eps file in Photoshop to SVG via Export As... the resulting SVG code (when opened in a text editor) is:

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="208" height="208" viewBox="0 0 208 208"><image x="6" y="18" width="196" height="172" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/></svg>
```

We're trying to alter the color of the svg via `fill: #000000 !important;` but no luck. I know that when you have a path you can alter the path via CSS fill but we're having trouble figuring out how to either export this in the correct format via PS or how to style this svg > image output via CSS.

We've also tried inserting the svg via `<img src="cart.svg" />` and styling with no luck there either. Any advice/help/direction greatly appreciated!

Comment: That looks like its just a png image embedded in an svg (and you cannot style the contents of a png).

Comment: If you have an `eps`, in Illustrator you should be able to go *File > Export > Format - svg > Show Code*. Copy the code and paste it into https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ to clean up all the useless stuff from illustrator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately what you're trying to do isn't possible.

> SVG files displayed with  are treated as an image: external resources aren't loaded, :visited styles aren't applied, and they cannot be interactive.

[MDN Web Docs: SVG element reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/image)

Do you have any access to the SVGs themselves and the code that calls them? Also, if you can open the EPS in Illustrator instead, you may have better luck.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, we just have the eps file, will try to export in illustrator to see if we can get the proper SVG export code

Answer (score 2):

Consider using [CSS filters](https://drafts.fxtf.org/filter-effects/#interpolation-of-filter-functions) to change svg coloration instead of `fill`

For example, red color can be obtained with this combination of CSS filters:

`filter: invert(21%) sepia(93%) saturate(7500%) hue-rotate(358deg) brightness(110%) contrast(119%);`

You can get the desired combination of filters for a specific color using the utility

https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp

[image]

*Hover to change color*

```css
 .img {
 filter: invert(0%) sepia(0%) saturate(0%) hue-rotate(151deg) brightness(106%) contrast(104%);
 }
  .img:hover {
 filter: invert(21%) sepia(93%) saturate(7500%) hue-rotate(358deg) brightness(110%) contrast(119%);
  }
```

```html
 <svg class="img" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="208" height="208" viewBox="0 0 208 208">
 
  <image  x="6" y="18" width="196" height="172" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/></svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not a vector image, you can't alter its color using `fill` or `stroke`, but you can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter) to achieve it as a workaround:

```
style="filter: brightness(0);"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="208" height="208" viewBox="0 0 208 208" style="filter: brightness(0);"><image x="6" y="18" width="196" height="172" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,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"/></svg>
```

```
style="filter: sepia(1) brightness(1.3) contrast(2) hue-rotate(-45deg);"
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="208" height="208" viewBox="0 0 208 208" style="filter: sepia(1) brightness(1.3) contrast(2) hue-rotate(-45deg);"><image x="6" y="18" width="196" height="172" xlink:href="data:img/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMQAAACsCAYAAAAkAQNcAAAgAElEQVR4nO1d63Ucx7Gu4vF/42YARWAoApMREP6JIXBIR0AxAkoRWIxA4AE4/GkwAlMRCBkIjuDiRlD39Ew/vqquWWCBnX32Z1MAdufR09PV9a5iEaGGzaJ7c3EkIifMTOl9xN9PiOho+JuIZPz8nohuzXG3X/vr+/Yan49GEDMDFvuxiBwz899E5IiZx8+JSUgo/Az/D+8jLH4C4qC48ANFDMfC7wb3THwrJHdE9F9mvo3EcreHUzsLGkGsEGfdeVjwYVcP//4efw47PIV5NhwgYSSC8e+0yNkQxPAZEE8mjHjtdCRed7jnSGiBe3wnod+J6Xv/5ep2N2Z0/WgE8QwMBED8UkheM/PLuPMPF1QLP65L9fn4Zb65EYHUoMrCp8JF3PtIEqvUddM1808KBMI3QvLta399s23zukk0glgSZ915EHPeCskpER07cr9a1Gk3T78nwsDFTXZnByTuoTgCchW4RgISS76nIRb47l5EAlF8/tpff9+GOd4kGkE8At2bixMReUtEp0EXGM7wFjRwggSzM8dDinikdAfvGkJKTEqwCxtFLTxn/NAZU/qC1RjvmPkXIrrpv1wdpJLeCGIBzrrzd0T0nolPPNnd26W9v60ibLlKgneOUqwjSYm9riE8PB7v7XEn9/7MgWt8IqJfD8161QjCIFiFSOgnIQmEcORYcipUC9HK92aBJ06hvnNEK2/BTukK6pgpDmTH8YBiT4OuQR++9teXq5rfbUcjiIhoHv2Jmd8H5ZhQ5gcTp2cN8nZ+xBTBENXyv7qvp0Og6RVgrz+lpNcWqvRjYhzjt7dE/KHvr/Zex2gEMYpGPzPRe4ocwe7wZGV253fv+EVmU3pAh6hFpalFC9zG9V0UboIchhY8j3quwsrC578GHWOf9YuDJojuzUUwlf5mrUUJlbkyLSZHxrcLe5EZFT/3zntIxyBvbMWTra1Lzrn2/kiYeLy1UEUEJ98/vvbXe+nLOEiC6LqLwAkCIQTTqStn0wO7b0Jl4YnwdttFc211CGtReuhcyhxH+zfGywhu9IrPLNJJFnIPoSBC/To5qB3FwRHEWXf+kpn/PXiQTfjDlDLsfjcRPuGJNx5hTJlRPTOrt+t7XIC8Reydk451CDmNIT5MxanMern82l//c+GE7xgOiiC6Nxc/E9FHlNdr0aeIHlZkn1r8tT+ihGngDpzPKwswiB938bgQd/R/Rlz67phTgzf8BP7+awgRybFRhrCIjCKdznPEM5rgRsh1HJEujPvVvphnD4IgzrrzsIj+LSIv81L0dnxa4EE24Reu7I/bdbFOBWdXWPS/h58kdEdMt3Mppl13ERyHx8T0MsRTxQDCo/wQFRc0IpZn3nVER9wwhOSWmV/tg7K99wQRA+6CiHSSPbSPkOkTPJ1iSmmOx35not+J+PucC38ZBE87Cb0NRJK5iCMWEfl6hP3c82mEkPR9IIq9Joiuuzghpv/kiFO1+8UPmGpxySqeTswQ7JRhAdyIyLcg4mz7gujeDBwk+FreMZiZK3+HxYR3m7RuEkLPd1p82luCCEF4RCMxTFlwlLjgKbMQe6RCIIIHl0ci2OVo0a67eCckHwcRy9ObHLNtba6t5ihwxR/X/jArwl4SROIMyeNMjt0eUdn9Sx6BtQgFJXgIftunGJ/uzcU7kZEwrKHAWqkQmMhkrGY7a33aO4IICjQR/ZlTLzGwTfSuN2V2rcIjhELIwqe+v9rb3IFoePiJRD5ai5jncSfSc+RYnz70X3bPT7FXBBHjkf4zZK2ZkIUENx4ITZRaebyLwW0Hk0QT8z1+E0rKtwnzcB17NXHE737ctey8vSKIs+7838x8WplInfgcNy6oEE8Qhz597a9/Xu8TbA+67iIQxTsia2p1UmFNCiso2cHE/OMuWZ5ebMEYVoKz7vyngRgcLzFZTpHFZFbfx5/BfPjjIRNDQN9fBR0g6wF5/oA4VHrF8LcRr5iOo26yM9gLDjHY2Yn+8EIiyIQdPBCv88uhE4JFsEQR07880/XiYEMVehL8EzsROr4XHCJGrI5AZ3HctdRXAjkAhRhChtg/GjHU6PurkBz0SkTuB1FzQQGECWLQ72fLsfMEMeYyDKVfBhR2Pr6c4X/xJXq8MLzoGIvTqk9MICrGHzyrUiYENc/g8xmPO45xZFuPnRaZotf1T+VFreKJjBKogznvhejVvsb2rxpdd/5OiIbd3sQyqTvZ4gbROhXm+odt99/sOof4bVT0xj+Gl8TxBWHCl6DtPKMRw5Lox9zqIb963GDGeR44MhovcP6zCDXoID9t+zPuLIcIeQ0hNMNL4LcFwBznUSj5+KrvWwW7p+CsO/8jhpxXJW+8GlQmo++H/svV1pbW3GUO8VFZlMpOFP+sw7fTS2Masr0aMTwRzAxhGUZvYBCXChMZNqn43bttfradJIiQCz2UjozBZaOoxJWFiRJhRLFKxu3s1/6AyqrMgaBkc4jpMolPSbEuPgsqORjRQiUi74dSP1uKXeUQb9Fy5Mbzg4kQjgme0182MuI9Qx9M1Mx3Vn/IlqWi2KnQjpistLVcYucIYiwkJu/Si8AXgtuVraNEkdUfaonGOSAi/8TNKHEFNMPiZ5Tei8j7bX2mXeQQ4+4iQtYgoF6CCdtg5std8ZbuCkJx5JAUlfSzqriBCZkBjh38Ei+38TF3jiBC0eHkbGbiQhiiCYBgx4riUxOV5sEvST/L+hpgKnQ8iL3b+DA7RRDRETd4pTlxBPA/0ES+s5Bcti468yBy3cJ5IVwGQ2esF1tETrdRud4tDiFYWKwO0kv/EvuG3alxhzkh9FktfOQY4LjLHHx8P0epUNw2YddEptfDf415NccvpZBkTSs3jTvMixAAGMvtqPswikxRrE2Im9fft+1Zdo0gXuaYe2XmxsQfUoo1EX3b3HAPB8ycgyPL3KudK/5Q4fmNQzwVMVSjhGlEh09R5kxiUHwZh9TbYKMQCg1WqpgmNHBgRGz8/GjbrE27xCFemlIwKnOrypIb30ML6V4T+v4qVCW8rUysIColfmHSTBtBPAWhv3M6LYdsZCWOa7v3KEr9vivPtw8IXU2TQSNZmFBEyvWbUsDlGLL/epsefWcIIjY9h1pBxdKEIeCYNy0izRG3XtykvBQrIiUgJ4/fnWx2yBq7JDKVrDhCNuyUXaTRqtFyHdaLMN9Dqin4INDUSmScpvHzbdIjdoIgkgNHKWS51mqRVSG8O3zauMMGwMQ3nvmVHKIA3a8RxJLI3CHXBsrm1trpE//bfA+bwe8Y1Jd0vBx+j0lbhXD+ti2D3wmCUOHEQpXuoMICyub0382M9sDBNIiphVuziiAojjqYJpGt0SN2giAwVkmsDc8kvGd/hFfSvWF2DMlDPFEbi4tuoT4nPt6WN7MzHCJhUonGSV9wTMMaIPQdAitLkGXySWDJv7jJbYtivTscIv+hCSSFHGNudTT3tUSgDSG02KreUfmrmGRJxTdtReTrThBESuypyidmx88I0e1lm5Vpc/hvbWkqZYAYN7niP9oKPWKX/BA5JqkqqluXsf/efBAbxS36GVS+CoTuG6L56zYMfHcIQuhDrKdUgsawQBnl38MxHzY30IbYacn4i/TfKn9ljEdrHGIZ9P3VUFxsaAFLOsAPEArytgJkG0bOP8HKJ6YyCv4TsTapzWGn8iHCQv/aX/9IPPQtCMnt95E4gr4QuMIPjRi2BmMIB6HDlLS1SYeCbwWH+MsWjGFp9F+uLlGnaNhK3BLJy+IeEmIxqb3aSNKsTA37ixxWA6E1ts5fwjb5jRpBNMwGE0pT4tAIUkqpOFO7bvNVOBpBNMyF3zFZi7JiXVVEgd8374vYSR2iYTdQyuDrQnLqd4Ysui0QnRqHaJgFuQp4ThYCMyzGMgmGg2/+XTQO0TALlL4w/KgLyyVkv9IWEETjEA3zQDAiH/pzqGoprL7fBjQO0TAPUhi+aCIY/zDhHFjdb8NoBNEwLzIR6GJyuT9dIgzZjqSuRhANs8DjALk5Y6k6AP65OoJ5E2g6RMNsKMoyhOZjUxsUo7bDyKQ5xFl3HoqBvQ9J38lcpmS/CK9BenVcbtdKLivMx3ts1Lr1oSl72mXcZuGsr4vnEdaFtR1KSV9ffRedSXhtjPV35wCaxVdJTU6SE+6c6tq2+Brek50xw3epIaJ9dns9Mu9Z7+y0+LltaLee82Mcvy4yB8/lrK850HXnx0T8XkhO4HlD3sYnrA6f+1R33XloovdRL7zcW7hauMXpol+eXdA0sdA9qF5x3oswDfzURD9AvJbI6oVfE7b7Ii0B5xvpvnZ2AbqEKGmpagIUQzi42PC51Pya4l9TmwqlyzhzWc1NdR1T8cTAztXUJqPWGHz2tb+ehTK6Nxc/i8hHmn7fv/Rfrn6mJDJ13cVADPmEUpW2enis7pzd8FiyUG2aCwoCQFU3PDY7brCvtKnUQN5izV/oBBQcEwaZMXTMtIvZ9jFQ1hFb0RrKNqpBwI96cWNeMXQ6msxD1iZLNY+WGPD50jOS3onFlP/U36FJtDSfsU1qsBZW9U6cuTBJXOW1CFXfrxLDRh96mqei2NimuUgTHwPRDOMIYpKI/DklvuC+bqkriQZJrKgqcC9YuB63KLuwZvdp9haJTVO7Mr4sIqrHwjXBaxGlClP2ORXcXz9rbT1J3JUcQoE1oriSN1ZvzCiyVeIeilR6QC5XsuKblR7ShXyRzVGi8fmde62aQ4QWbLi2rQhXjYn4hxeBlbjEkBQgfNC0++bKCVA4zO7C2DEGXyLDjm2q7qWBgeEhV2fA3T5xMXUulJ+piM+bADK7RCIqFCsMVJJLVYVOTWx5VuR8aofnWn6O1exU1WwpY81zZubNLqziEDOLlYGopGJk9fPiOrDyvzmOyXlXON/gtdbElr9beaXF0CQ+F0rD9wVjUuuU6OMLjkWiPFEAgTuz3bnjSfXD58Xr7NSOYoxl7sks5IqlTuzYBPdW38OCVuwTfxK8pHKyelZciJ7srryvuA+A3kVUNhuPeHMwnJ0jwTPLuVacVIQNG0Z6r+m6Lpd2iMw+k94wC1djRywlEvUekbgYKqbMQRBMfFpxLyrvtBor0/ELYnrp6Qh4ETt5mRWSWjlqkSFwweHE5OsZ64USGeAYLbJpvYEykelKfpWcn7nc9POSISDc1ZIMikSWdzwUistF1fgFCBLns1qbXM8REiw5EaNlxy86BLILtbCN+JhFLdu0UulXKLrC/JXJ1M+aRV/nHZo5X7UOcdadn4YFrtabbb9mQ9NFXr5I9YuqgVoxiCpqSk9UbmgUJ+Q0qMSmiUG5Ga/BZrErQsgPpzvlpwWE3ELd22Rtebs7fq7YqrlW/AIMAGIWhv+C8+6MBEnlF6tUV5ytqKhlTEmXs4SQxuhwKpxbUgTJlc6BUoEQbm6+ouyGX+DcwNpKcxvXykqb2zDza7XWSFtCcRLAaPA96BCKVWUWjg8GWnm+oNmB0+f1DmAGSnVe7aRYBDKpIsIJuZdhAVdiiFGUFVHCF4XI/OdIixmV0KRLoRiUR28ICQnSipP5c2OBQ86Km1JRFotOlTmgeQaxcwkian5Ah8Ol++EYLIRgXZg51dyzzCEZnYyJVlYc4qw7PwotnCvLJW5wxjAQd5u7wCE+EyyaMgG10pVfFDsr3SyAzKJR+SNnR4XFiiws740TliK1QMyulWRXdRwmoRi2qW3vKKqhjO6bGUkdT3qhGk6EnAoxpUPgOZkQra7Gmv1bXZBgwdZibnmvee4tEZkx4HMqhRS4cvrce0dqIy3juuv761X2Awzi0lF6NpRM9IOzHjPT5xdf++sgMt3lF4+Kmq3WjKXnQdas/oHSlmRuwk0Cdw1zLr4zK+sSUTWxeeIrBZn08UnOtpYl2F3L7p8mr/Q1sApoNWa7Q5sGkRlSFrBdsISLFsUu0d8r4iYjthqiKeKWX+BN4F6V5czA4154riJ2Ls+ax+1YB+O4/lnd7Hl4XRZHeVb1/mrDw10omfoifnlTXjzs5GbHQuWymjDY7QXlMiosnWDBVMBdzuyCItqagrsL8nzcyfCByxDTtTRBqZ84eaw/U+KGNtdpwsMd1foOWC92lzhhR0uiD3LZLHdbIjWcKh2fF6zhsvYcC4+bETlcSvSY7Zznn8hNxue+J6Z/xE15Jei6i2A1PVUc1fHfKBFwXNcDh3oRv/xE9sXYmHWGBQWlzsksUMtemc3LdRRsdS0jL1cLAYUY1l7fvMCAuxHsBtaKlAhf7ejIZYw4p54LVFy8thIZ8n31DmXnoroXcgwjj0+Ji/YYu4BRX7H3wk3H24zU78BNcde3xFktunLNQAShXP4vJPRD/+Vqta2TmU7V+oGup0qigfmKa2Dss50e+Kw7/4OJT+JF9WQiu9VhDrd9f/XjSh+ooeEZ6N5c/IGVxCsxubLwDWt7rAiJ4d/M/BkpXbE/yH4S7Us46d5cbFVb1YbDxVl3HtbiSeYGNlAx6YUJRZ/6nD7KBCEil8pJkc9BeVqLFPG7t20NNmwDmFmvRdCDjfnS6g+5LGomiK/9dShOe2OVLE+2NXrCaVsNDVsBkVO08ukEJNDF0JTJdNN/ucrdplTGnJB8q2zWxkRFxv4uIseDm7yhYYPo3lycCtGxsvKl9WtyZtCAIyLfcNSKIL7215dDwxGrpZPxOdQmzddtMTRsFDKuQeuvQieh3dSZ+D6seRy2l1N9g7ZbtPcr05vOhDrt3my+UG3DYSKsPSEZpBTPFK0iKDBkhKQy+VYEISKflZ0Z5K0SFVnZnY+aLtGwKYhI8D0cec5YAi85+rQoWVYNKoIIXkMM+HODukBTh0E0salhI8iRrcbog6E16HykFD8Vu9sipsrQ3MSzCpQJC+Pgs6x2ejZUNmhoWB/imjvliUgAKks0/pojGVwP+RRBfEoLHiMh08WU2x9phrmJTQ1rRVpzVYwWhgyRjjSOq/aTN06XIGKdmtsU64MRkmQUFyVOSXPSNawdb1WwqRTpZUE23m3/5cpNWZ2s3IfKdbX4pfZTRMproRwNa8Ow1oROlGXJhMLnkCNREduVMp2wqJTlpQ13VnZcE+kK3zUu0bAegERik6wIIqQpRbeWiO3JDraTBBFCOUKMOHqlwX5bJ1yUv5se0bAWBN+DF3ZeiUq5Lfawbm9imJKLhcWO0a0t8L+JY3MoR3CjtyXRMCdiuNBYQkkXKxjuOpXxR0TfFg1rIUFEt7aiJuZadyhOj5wz0XwSDXPjdZUMBYkO2e+gDUL3sen/JB4shx9YjDJZYU5zSRojTNkLrGyofNDQMAPC2kITv819sNmaUPDgwey8x/SH+Iz5zoSpEbZIcPFeHzWfRMOMOB3ChSDNwabdYuooYNK6lPAgQUT39h1SYI4tz5UmBMSlPLAmNjXMhddlM8ZyNho5mmLcvN1QDYvHdRBiukFvn00+T0V6U4peNG21UI6GlWNo6hOqakAznsQRUuWVFJFNGOk6Eaph8TiCEN/NTSZeBBWYyKqa2NSwUgRR3KkcVHwOzpqMROKvYYNHEUTfXwWR6VZVkzPl+9JgSnUDJ8e1oeG5iM64tPKqQD6u12QI1cC2Wc8miHjxz8rWi7V4cihHVaCrhXI0rAxdd3ESwoMoGTlN/S6bDwFppA8q0wnLdCG9hJ1/vCF4rkUpN6owWOMSDSuBkETuUBcMQL0BC+1xqijzSDyaIFJVjlSSEAegIGB9Gr9vekTDShAaoKTr5MqPpv4vFhKIHGJhqIbFcn2qhb7lMpGGGrCsIYFs10I5GlaBrrsYGqAMl0r1cUk7i1GEAiwM1bBYiiD6/uqSmO6tQy6FbSgvdkQccPNJNDwLQvIa689ilDUWcTaVNaqqGg9hOQ4x3uSGMNrVik1eP+tWlaPhGYhhQKOUAXWXsAgZFsYgenyohsXSBMEUasDWVbKt9xplOpLBzd7EpoanYgjVUAo0AhVoHc/0aOtSwtIE0fdXuSqHpcpxJM5Jo4m2iU0NT8VYhIxM2X5dxptMj8O7p/SdWJog4s1ulKxGTm8D01cgiE0tlKNhWYTm6xzFJSwrM8A2t9TFup/Ud+JJBDFU5TAtiUq9myJCOWl9TWxqWAohJi6ngCaY0pQ2n3rMo54IN3oATyKIULEgNJnIFAuKtIAoZc2zTC2Uo2FpvI2LSpVSRZ+DquY9Simhkc+TGsE/lUOMyrVpMGhLgeTvWlWOhicgrBVmPlEdgGiCGKAI2aKqGg/hyQQhJJfWvIoDS3AsA41LNDwKIvJWBe+l+sKOpYm1iL6U7wHxZIJIVTnygIxOoZRs3Yq16RENj8Wpao6YN1vIgeCSQx2/Vw1QlsWTCSLeXVXlyAM3nmpCihZqDVYaHkQI92Hm45z7YJJ+EFmEGj9fKlTD4lkEEUI5mMZQDmX+gqhD26QiynnNJ9GwECHcJ+feZOONcXIZ5TpU1Vg2VMPieRxiGNTY9N2kL2HZ8SJKlXDxFsrRMAkVqqEq8RVMBPQ9u+f1swki1IDNJlanYTjl4MTS6zpU5WihHA1TiBVbxg0TnG1V8THLMJ5hXUp4NkEE93hwk9vBYSsugj515bgWytHgI4hLqERnMpCKI+S05RBO9JiqGg/h+SLTONAblQdBrt6gMuuEqIVyNFQYq2rwKaGPAYhDm1sFU0mfLS7RygiC6JNtWUSmtRGIS+N3rcFKg4NhTSRBgn2rZdFFFZ4UqmGxEoIYqnIw3xJ4CxGKUPJX3BqsNFQIzjhCY4xKRnMccuNxj66q8RBWxSEG5ZpypQMtMqnPtEf75Kw7b6EcDQPiWjixPeEyoG86On5XoUwnrIwg0F3uJXJkiq8z7RqXaBiAdbxQ0lAlZpS7K0c/PMv3gFgZQQyhHDSGciCLmxSfyrM1PaJhQOw3XRUuHn+pyhul454VqmGxSg4RBvgNvYvFwlo55rI5lolbVY6G3AClChJNEdVovcS8h2eGalislCCC25yZ7216X6nRbHrWlfzX5pNoGNaAEpNidhwWxlP1l0gebICyLFZKEJSrcoBDxcQ5JZYHORLh49Zg5YBhG6AgbCcgU+poJb4HxMoJIlQ6AGVnQCYCU4gWxKsjrMrWcFgYKnqLHCmOkFuRaAON6Ra0MutSwsoJYqh0wDTahBmq/KXIRIKqa/Gc8WGb2HSwEHqtw3qwvLe2WkKawZOqajyEOThEEZtM6PcA7OqiIxlPu+6ihXIcGGL4zmkyO476p98TnRLH4LLGVo1ZCALd6DbnWtmS69apTWw6PJzazZFMaXvsdgth3ysJ1bCYhSAGN7rQLTZ7x2YraEpLiGJVc9IdHsa86SkHHNfSRGiAEiq/zDFTc3GI8BCfU1MVW5/JpgACG2yhHAeE8K6HqhqQXYmlKFU/QwzniGFCc2A2gghNKnRSh7YS6NTAcl5rw3U4sO8aLZG2G5DZWFfqe0DMRhC5wUpuvxXBCzyQqVJbw6HgFEN51DqwfaeLvrlUA5RlMZ/INGJwq6NyVEW/mmIEodJCC+XYfwyhGiLHaS3kKAanWLYJ+V5pqIbFrASRQjnS3/jQVuFWZTFbKMfeg5lfi82VEfRRsRKhaJQknl1V4yHMzSEGe7H1WqfgvlIPFkSoGMrRda0qx74iVFxB0bj0g5PiowLr0uiZHqvOzz0lsxPEUAM2/67lQSxVk4+JoRzEzSexr4hh3mrDy5wCSxqJsUrOaF1KmJ0gQoMVojGUo4SD65BwLHdJxczWxKY9RShUZ2t1kSkiUNVdIrrrZwjVsJidIAZEsUnnxEKZEbA3l81BWijHHqKEaoywPqmEwi1Ke911zMZ6CALc7DnQj2oHHZlKbIEo1jK+hnXiFPNi7HsnTCCTJEzIbKEaFmshiOhmv1U9wEy0a7Y66TKYzUm3f9DOuDqeDb7Mv80WqmGxHg5hSl6OjKHwByxilrnHqEy1Bit7hPgu8/v0iIG9wL4Z8h6msDaCYOZLVcFZ9RlOP0yv4fHjxiX2B2PNJQjwxG5T6LHGOl4yY6iGxdoIIlZGuBHgDWhRwGypLGO2Bit7hcHcmh4Iej2o6AUu5paUJjpnqIbF2ghigNA3ho6SqtRlTAxRHSbHXaQ1WNkDhHcYKqykLV9JAmhIEYnFsTNmDdWwWCtBhAYrInKfLAc5rDdXpSleGeO8az6J3cdrFZmAWiSIT+nzqFeuvKrGQ1gvhxgX+I11xkQXdqnslyYo5VOMTd9bKMeOQlXVAH2RwQyvCmJzbp+wFt8DYu0EISSfseUWOuV0Yz0V5diqcuwwclUNiHamFLDg9IsDnXJt1qWEtRNErJRwpxu6U7EwQOW/hGiCbWLTriJV1UARiYrvyW6INL7zlTRAWRZrJwgyVTmwALKVKU0VtxbKsYMYQjV49E5joWtlVfKdc2sXl2hTBDFU5WBwRAqV3YOgsK01z7ZQjp2DqsiX/LLQXKcqNlGkg7WEalhshCBCVY7Q5EK1Sorf2WRzU7mtOel2DKkBSgYXZdqt8j1iZQ1QlsVfNjW9IU8iVNnwelkjME4+HN91F++CDoJRsgzsBjufmmYC1fXtvbE6ORbVpSjWYSUIe091PDobbShzbVpcfC1zvPo9ieXw0+uwo3IMnHxlM8fu/fFcO251LKt3djxU1RC9seGYXHFpDXkPU9gYQRDTJQv/S9XwNInmGOMErvzfhh+iFwumoSbnTjpAnCoO1uKRIfrYUly3Et+q42yikwpDYE0k+Tsn6lMtalzkNsRFSog0WeLGonDZnB1nIuWd6PehAiuJauKyx1rFOI3NhmLAS1BOV7yPyatfq+8BsSkdYgjlEBqVa9MAo8iRrF8Q1viMH7gWqXQtgQ0Ur2uLHMQTbDmcUi7HZvWpl56HkhdvLsdINZewBgPlkBJVAFp57u3zEd7Pez6sa5TOs2NBQk6bERCGynsnu8vr8TDVYy73EUXYqgQRZk7GbqKrbICyLDZGEDROwDerOKudHHbRpFfggjmiDTkAAARDSURBVE/HUNq00mIyIQF298z3J8jQwzxeI4IIFeLLKKswfq4DE8txupQnXqcsCp09VhTN0k9NXdUSLtcczQRIFgU25y/j5XSrqrydsN6kFCFVR4PFEEU0cLoq7lhCc9R7XXeohgVPssU1oXtz8b8kdOQpWO4ihp1ZnGNVlKTpfqpkeUJRQosB6TpIjPiZGoeRnfUYfcVRjdXqPmZ3t8+d/57QP6r5gufIQLYJog/+9Oa9OhYWeLm0aHrwdYvq3vGk+76/+p/q5mvERjkEgU/CfJgnz7LVwiFIvZDJ3FzgQKrcCb5Ho4yqiNt8SBHh0ktW4etGcfaIoTIYUInnqp7PMS6440O7geE81eJDEyeExyRxzwKLQNScB8YbuWqJUfKfJ4uqUKAuPUO8zkZ8D4iNE8TQUpX1SxR46VlcSMd4Sh9r30UhonicXTz48lOULVpvHJm+0JKzqJBAjWHAfWarFzk1cBUxTiTSROXAJSJ3IabzSoxYFnO8ebYcQ/2Mm4DHzVE0rCJa0/tVryBfZ2PWpYSNi0w0ejP/DA33POXRmkLJTr4jEljxg0hzE0/sUWKY5UDOdfGtouikzcGkFNnJxWO+r6+jF6d9VisOeefacVt9xx4z5SOw4qO9huVKVjxCoGgVTOlf++sfaMPYOIegcXJVKIdW3updL9s/WMv5FXGbioAELw3FizKQpPhqUyJeO3+em3toE6cWjXR8VrpWtl49QCyFSIGDZc4Aoh9wLLKETqCQG10HFWdlJbKmb48DIfcAjlNdHxRnaxHErMl1FCF7DLaCIIKb3k6WNs3Vsjfa5GsfRGHb8QRryfDFHiDIajczY0NRShGirXiOm7c6rlbyrXhDVjklUmPzNgvr4Y9/VGNF/4EWJ5NIo83T2YKnrqudjWoc1jROWryzG4CIbCRUw2IrCKLvr0Ioh3LG6Ik1dms2rN5aapxdDc/Fl5x20EmZ3eT8pl0Px6mIUd1HO51Q0bVWGiu64YZQW5iKzqRl87qnApPeT5QeBs3Q9Tn6ORUxGh+ERI7i+Wn0eyqEmfW0cv3LTYVqWGwLhwiT9CHEN9nFSaDI4kuzeoLafaEKYPobLlZZY5AXWA+25Sx2B0/XrDiOlMWHix296ur5VQhFba/HhU/e2OwzZ24B483jhM3COD/RWkTOu3CBBhCz4bj2BYZ/oTwR0YeHb7IebA1B9P3VPTO/IuJfiWpWnIB6g/08oYg9IwTMuETld3xhnrhCeUc1i8ZwHNyt7fna6lWLIUofMaZYJRpJuVf8UD+3JNHQnyvUccjOFeldP4tTVCxw1tyqOK7r+dabkRKRypyHd/1qk55pi62wMlnEdNFQv+clflUcOKJ2UbJKnrezGesSWmPydYzoRbhzW6eaY4Gyi8NCcQEgFu9cNcYFz2U55aPubafGOBg9S5w3b1P3KxYoY60rcxwSf0Lxsa0hhAFE9P81qG2/Ky7HEgAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="/></svg>
```

Comment: This does work but we're trying to manipulate via css `fill` so we can easily alter the color for multiple states